# LINUX [UBUNTU]: screenlog.0 - modify path

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu-screen

I have a screen command like this:

```
screen -A -h 1500 -m -dmS SKY-001 /home/SKY-users/SKY-001/./ ...
```

I'd like to start the output logging and save the screenlog.0 file to `/home/SKY-users/SKY-001`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes, there is a logfile option. But you're off-topic here...